# Can MS Access make a column-of-rows type of form like the one pictured?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, database, forms, report

I am trying to make a form consisting of multiple forms stacked side-by-side in Access, like the one pictured below but have run into many, many issues. I will settle for a report if I can't get a form to work.

The data has multiple workers, each worker can have multiple jobs. Each job has a number, a description, and a time (how old it is). Using a continuous form as a sub-form I can get the jobs of each worker listed.

Here are the problems I've encountered;

1. the parent form can't be continuous (though this may not be an issue)
2. I can't get the workers to list side-by-side
3. the rectangles in the sub-form can't be different colours; I change one, it changes all to match

If this can't be done in something like form designer, does this look like something that I could achieve in VBA if I went at it? Is it too crazy that I contemplate it? I do code, but in Java and C++ mostly (and Matlab, but I don't see that helping). Also, I have little to no experience with Windows coding. I realise this last bit is a bit open-ended, but I don't want to get too far down a dead-end and Dr Google hasn't been that helpful (some related, but nothing really like my problem).

If it matters, Access 2010 is what I've got, but *might* be able to stretch to 2013.

[image: Example form]